# Is it possible to make predictions with Gaussian process regression using noise-free observations with the GPML toolbox?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, gaussian-process

I have just started to use the GPML toolbox for Gaussian process regression, and I need to apply it to a case where my observations are noise-free. From reading the GPML manual it is my understanding that noise is automatically assumed when using the Gaussian likelihood function, and as a result I can't see a way I can apply this toolbox to make predictions with noise-free observations. If anyone can help me out, it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps GPML is no longer the best software for GPs, check out GPflow or GPy for Python implementations. I think the best way to do is to just override your hyp structure to have a likelihood variance of zero, remembering that it gets transformed by exp(), so use a large negative value. Then when you call gp function for predictive mean and you will get 0 variance at data points (chart below). This is a bit of a hack as its happening post optimization. If you want to just calculate through matrix multiplication look at GPML book follow the formulas but switch K + I$ \sigma^2$ to just K. Then feed to one of matlab's inbuilt optimizers, for the kernel hyps.

In GPflow you can turn off before optimization.

[image]